# google earth enterprise - javascript api URL

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

google's documentation says the google maps javascript api can be used to access the maps of google earth enterprise but doesn't say how the script src need to be specified..

to access google maps api, i use src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"

can somebody provide directions on replacing this URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a Google Maps for Enterprise key with the Google AJAX API Loader, you just load the common loader using your key:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=YOURKEY&sensor=true"></script>
```

See: https://support.google.com/code/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=92831

You would then use the URL of an alternative Earth Enterprise database to connect to instead of the default database via the [google.earth.createInstance method](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#a70288485024d8129dd1c290fb2e5553b). For example.

```
var options = { database: 'http://yourserver.com/database/' };
google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB, options);
```

You may have to alter your Google Earth Server configuration before Google Earth Plugin instances will be able to connect to it using this method, it depends on the earth server version.

Really though, for help and support with the enterprise versions of Google Earth you should contact enterprise support. That is what it is there for after all.

Comment: thanks Fraser.. i don't have a chance to test this now.. if somebody who is using this finds a problem, please comment here..